# Fortran Coarray cant compile

Tags: fortran, fortran-coarrays

Im trying to compile an example of Coarray Fortran file.
https://github.com/ljdursi/coarray-examples
The command for compile is:

```
mpifort diffusion/diffusion-coarray.f90 -fcoarray=lib -o diffusion/diffusion-coarray -L ${PATH_TO_OPENCOARRAY_LIB} -lcaf_mpi
```

I've already installed the OpenCoarrays, using `spack` 
But there is an error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcaf_mpi
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Without `-lcaf_mpi` the error is:

```
/tmp/ccOdrmfc.o: In function `MAIN__':
diffusion-coarray.f90:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `_gfortran_caf_num_images'
diffusion-coarray.f90:(.text+0x4c): undefined reference to `_gfortran_caf_this_image'
diffusion-coarray.f90:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `_gfortran_caf_this_image'
diffusion-coarray.f90:(.text+0x77): undefined reference to `_gfortran_caf_num_images'
diffusion-coarray.f90:(.text+0x8a): undefined reference to `_gfortran_caf_num_images'
diffusion-coarray.f90:(.text+0xaa): undefined reference to `_gfortran_caf_this_image'
diffusion-coarray.f90:(.text+0xbd): undefined reference to `_gfortran_caf_this_image'
diffusion-coarray.f90:(.text+0xf4): undefined reference to `_gfortran_caf_num_images'
```

End etc.
Where is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that /usr/bin/ld cannot find -lcaf_mpi, the library for open coarrays, possibly because it isn't installed. Can't say more without more information (at the very least the version of gfortran would be useful), but https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/CoarrayLib and http://www.opencoarrays.org/ might help. Oh, and in questions please put the source directly (as long as it's not too long), links break, so also breaking questions.

Comment: We need to know *how* and *where* you installed OpenCoarrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for help. I've solved the problem. If anyone will be interested, here is my solution:
1. Install Linuxbrew following their instructions:

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Linuxbrew/install/master/install.sh)"

test -d ~/.linuxbrew && PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$HOME/.linuxbrew/sbin:$PATH"
test -d /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew && PATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin:$PATH"
test -r ~/.bash_profile && echo "export PATH='$(brew --prefix)/bin:$(brew --prefix)/sbin'":'"$PATH"' >>~/.bash_profile
echo "export PATH='$(brew --prefix)/bin:$(brew --prefix)/sbin'":'"$PATH"' >>~/.profile
```

2. Install OpenCoarrays library `brew install opencoarrays`
   Now we can compile files with `caf` and `cafrun`
3. Compile .exe-file `caf fname.f90 -o test.exe`
4. Run the program `cafrun -np (numimages) test.exe`

Hope it will be helpful for someone!
P.S. My OS is **Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS**, gfortran: **GNU Fortran 5.4.0 20160609** so the rest of necessary tools (for example, compiler `caf` and launcher `cafrun` are the part of OpenCoarrays package) will be installed by following the instruction.

Comment: Thanks for getting back on this, and providing your solution. However to make your answer even more useful it would be good to add the versions of your OS, compiler and OpenCoarrays.

Comment: My OS is Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS, so the rest of necessary tools (for example, compiler `caf` and launcher `cafrun` are the part of OpenCoarrays package) will be installed by following the instruction.

Comment: Using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS for gfortran, it works too